# Call Function Inside ajax success results in ReferenceError: Can't find variable:

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im getting this error inside the AJAX success handler.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getresult

I'm trying to call a function called `getresult` but I get this error where it seems to think `getresult` is a variable? Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var data1 = $('#comments').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/modules/business/submitPost.php",
        data: ({ dat1: data1}),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#comments").val("");
            $("#comments").css('height', 'auto');
            $("#comments").height(this.scrollHeight);
            $('#imagepreview').attr('src', "");
            $("#imagepreview").hide();
            $("#faq-result").html("");
            getresult('/modules/business/getresult.php?page=1');
        }
    });
});

function getresult(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            rowcount: $("#rowcount").val()
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loader-icon').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loader-icon').hide();
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#faq-result").append(data);
        },
        error: function(){}             
    });
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        if ($(".pagenum:last").val() <= $(".total-page").val()) {
            var pagenum = parseInt($(".pagenum:last").val()) + 1;
            getresult('/modules/business/getresult.php?page='+pagenum);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is `getresult` defined?

Comment: outside the button click... just a regular function

Comment: see edits where i added the getresult function and widow scroll.  everything works but the call to the getresult function inside the success in the button click area

Comment: Is that how the actual code above looks? Is getresult actually sitting inside a ready method and the click is not?

Comment: getresult is in ready button click is not

Comment: putting the button click in the ready fixed it.  Its all good now... thank you.